# Satzstellung in Satz mit ob und Futur

Tags: word-order, modal-verb

Folgenden Satz habe ich spontan (ohne über die Sprache nachzudenken) geschrieben:

> Sie ist erkrankt und kann nicht sagen, ob sie die Reise wird antreten können.

Ich bin sicher, dass er korrekt ist, aber warum ist das „wird“ vorgezogen?

Anmerkungen:

> ..., ob sie die Reise antreten können wird.

geht natürlich auch.
Und am besten lässt man den Kontext über die Zeit entscheiden:

> ..., ob sie die Reise antritt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der Nebensatz hat ein sogenanntes *Oberfeld* direkt links von der rechten Verbklammer. Beim Perfekt mit Ersatzinfinitiv muss das *haben* in das Oberfeld gesetzt werden, beim Futur I und beim regulären Futur II kann man *werden* wahlweise in das Oberfeld setzen. Beim Futur II mit dem Ersatzinfinitiv muss man sowohl *werden* als auch *haben* in das Oberfeld setzen.